# How can I nest format string in Python2?

Tags: python, format

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter) % ((1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex8.py", line 2, in <module>
    print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter) % ((1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4))
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Is something wrong with my code? Or just can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use just one tuple for your formatting:

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter) % (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

If you want it to be more clear, you could do this:

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
tuples = ((1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4))
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter) % sum(tuples, ())
```

or better:

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
tuples = (1, 2, 3, 4) * 4
print formatter % ((formatter,) * 4) % tuples
```